# How to apply different layouts in gatsby js project

Tags: gatsby

The standard [`gatsby js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-three/#our-first-layout-component) project contains a `layouts` folder which looks like it supports multiple layouts. So how can I apply different layouts for different pages? The official doc doesn't mention it. Any experts can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In v1, layouts caused a bit of confusion (https://next.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-06-08-life-after-layouts). I'd recommend using Gatsby v2 that just employs pages+components. Much simpler.